# Implicit route, with firstOrCreate instead of findOrFail

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.5

Is it possible to create an implicit route where if it is not found the thing is created? I am using Laravel 5.5.13.

For instance this is my implicit route:

```
Route::post('thumbs/{player}', 'ThumbController@store');
```

And in my controller it is this:

```
public function store(Request $request, Player $player)
{
    $thumb = new Thumb($request->all());
    $player->thumbs()->save($thumb);
    return response()->json($thumb, 201);
}
```

So now if I go to the endpoint of `..../api/thumb/1` it will create a thumb related with `Player` of id `1`. However instead of a id number I wanted to provide it a string like this:

```
..../api/thumb/PLAYER_NAME
```

So example of `..../api/thumb/Blagoh`, then my endpoint should first find if a player exists by name "Blagoh", and if it doesn't then it should create it. I couldn't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is adding into `boot` method of `RouteServiceProvider` something like this:

```
Route::bind('player', function ($value) {
   if ($player = \App\Player::find($value)) {
      return $player;
   }

   return Player::create(['name' => $value]);
});
```

It's called explicit binding and you can update logic as showed above. [Reference - Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: Super cool thank you so much! How does `\App\Player::find($value)` know how to search by `name`?

Comment: @Blagoh It won't - in your example you showed value could be 1 and in this case search is done by id. If you want to look by name, `firstOrCreate` might be better choice

Comment: Oh whoops haha! Thanks for that fast reply! :)